# verilog compile error - "variable not constant"

Tags: verilog

Why am I getting error "`q is not constant`"?

```
module prv(
    input [7:0]x,
    input [7:0]y,
     output [49:0]z
     );

    wire [24:0]q;
    assign z=1;
  genvar k;

 for (k=50; k<0; k=k-1) 

   begin

     wire [25:0]a;
     assign a=0;
     assign q= x;
     genvar i;
     for(i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
      begin
        if(q[0]==1)
           begin
            assign a=a+z;
           end
        assign {a,q}={a,q}>>1;  
       end
      assign z={a[24:0],q};
    end

 endmodule
```

Comment: I am going to make a wild guess that this is an attempt to make a sequential multiplication like this one (Figure 3-13) http://users.utcluj.ro/~baruch/book_ssce/SSCE-Shift-Mult.pdf . If so, it needs a good amount of work to do it correctly. First and foremost, Verilog is a hardware descriptive language, and as such, should map very directly to the hardware it attempts to describe. The block above has none of the registers needed for the circuit provided. Please let me know if you'd like me to flesh this explanation into a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you are trying to use Verilog the wrong way. `q` is a wire, not a variable (a `reg`) so it cannot be assigned with a value that includes itself, because that would cause a combinational loop. You are using the `assign` statement as if it were a regular variable assignment statement and it's not.

Declare `a` and `q` as `reg`, not `wire`. `i` and `k` don't need to be genvars variables, unless you are trying to generate logic by replicating multiple times a piece of code (description). For `for` loops that need to behave as regular loops (simulation only) use integer variables.

Besides, behavioral code must be enclosed in a block, let it be combinational, sequential, or initial.

A revised (but I cannot make guarantees about its workings) version of your module would be something like this:

```
module prv(
    input wire [7:0] x,
    input wire [7:0] y,
    output reg [49:0] z
    );

    reg [24:0] q;
    reg [25:0] a;
    integer i,k;

    initial begin
       z = 1;
       for (k=50; k<0; k=k-1) begin
         a = 0;
         q = x;
         for (i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin
           if (q[0] == 1) begin
              a = a + z;
           end
           {a,q} = {a,q}>>1;  
         end
       z = {a[24:0],q};
    end
 endmodule
```

Comment: Close. `initial` should be replaced with `always @*` and the line `assign z=1;` should be removed.

Comment: This version of the module is valid for simulation only, and I don't thinik an `always @*` fits here because the code block doesn't model combinatorial behaviour. About the `assign`, you are right. That one I missed it :) Fixed it!

Comment: If it was `k>=0` instead of `k<0` then `z` would be a function of `x`, thereby combinational behavior. but the SO is also missing an `end` (I think it should be before the `z={...}`), so it will not compile.

Comment: Note my comment above that this is likely an attempt to implement a sequential multiplier. As such, it really shouldnt be purely combinational, and the OP didnt use `initial` or anything suggesting a simulation model. Also note no dependency on `y` for some reason. Though you havent yet explained that the reason for the original error which was using the wire `q` in an if statement outside any assignment block (`assign` or `always`), thus the need for a constant evaluation in compilation. However, as `q` is simulation-time variable, the compilation failed.

Comment: The OP has translated a sequential algorithm into Verilog. The way the OP has translated it makes it suitable only for simulation, so I have inferred the initial block as the only way to have a module that resembles what he wrote.
If he wanted to write a synthesizable module, then things would be quite different and the resulting module wouldn't have many recognizable parts from its initial implementation. This is why I have remodeled it as a simulation only module